# How to place a search bar on the Responsive image using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have been trying to place a search bar on my responsive image which is acting like my background. Please help me out on how can i achieve that. Thanks... Cheers :)   Here is my Code.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Image and text -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="images/Logo.png" width="50" height="50" class="d-inline-block align-middle" alt=""> SHOPPY
  </a>
</nav>

<img src="images/Background.jpeg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
```

Comment: So, where is `search bar` in your current code?

Comment: I dont have it yet because i dint know how to place it in the center of the image.

Comment: On SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Wrap the image with `div` with `position: relative, display:

   inline-block`. This way, the `div` will be the same size like the image (so responsive as well).
2. Wrap the input with `div` with `position: absolute` so it will place "on" the image and `width: 100%` so it will responsive in the same way the image.

Like this:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.search-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left:0 ;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.search-wrapper input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="images/Background.jpeg" class="img-fluid">
  <div class="search-wrapper">
    <input type="search" placeholder="Search.." />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried it and i am afraid that the Search bar is not in the middle of the image and is just at the start of the image aligned to the left. Help please..Thanks

Comment: I was updated my answer. Keep attention that I'm using `flex`, so you need to check if [you can use it](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://forms.soundestlink.com/image/form/popup/593a71b6597ed778f73cc5e9" class="img-fluid">
  <div class="search-wrapper">
    <input type="search" placeholder="Search.." />
  </div>
</div>

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

img {
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
}

.search-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    align-items: center;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    padding: 15px;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.search-wrapper input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Here you can add width/height for you input.

I think transform is the best solution to set input in the middle.

Comment: While your answer may be correct, it's mostly a block of code and a fairly long one at that. I'd argue that it also not meeting one requirement of https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer, which is that the question is poor. Splitting it into several sections and adding some explanation would help less experienced programmers. Also, a discussion of how to modify it to meet certain requirements like positioning wouldn't hurt. But overall, it is a good first try for a first answer.